# Clear UITextField when user hits home button

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone dev and am trying to figure out the best way to clear a UITextField when the user hits the home button. I don't see any 'obvious' methods in the default tab bar .m file I am messing with. I am using xcode 4. Any ideas with sample code would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which home button? The device main button? Then you have to handle applicationDidEnterBackground in your AppDelegate to do it.

On ViewControllers, you can subscribe for UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification on NSNotificationCenter

Comment: This looks like what I need to do. Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

This one is used whenever the user leaves your app, that means from receiving a call to power button pressed and also pressing the home button as you asked.
In this method you "pause" nicely your app, and as soon as your `applicationWillResignActive:`
returns, your app has entered background.